# The correct way to read from stdin in nodejs

Tags: node.js

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7439

The above page shows that `fs.readFileSync(process.stdin.fd)` does not work correctly.

Is `fs.readFileSync(fs.openSync('/dev/stdin', 'rs'))` the correct way to read from stdin? But it seems that it only works in certain cases, but not all case.

I am wondering what is the correct way to read from stdin in nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use readline

https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

from those docs:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
```

and to read lines:

```
for await (const line of rl) {
  // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
  console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `process` global has a `stdin` interface. This will log a line after a user enters text and presses `Enter` on the keyboard.

```
let buffer = ''
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.on('data', (d) => buffer = buffer.concat(d.toString()))

setTimeout(() => {
    // Exit after 5 seconds and print entered content
    console.log(buffer.toString('utf8'))
    process.exit(0)
}, 5000)
```

Docs - https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin

Comment: I want to read the whole stdin into a single string. Will this read the whole stdin?

Comment: Check my updated answer. It shows how you can capture all input for 5 seconds. Remove the setTimeout for whatever you're doing, I just put it there as an example.

Comment: If the input takes more than 5 sec to process, what will happen?

Comment: Just remove the timeout. It was an example to force the program to close. Without it it will keep reading until some condition you define is triggered.